# How do i make that it will register to the click event but won't add the items more then once in the richTextbox mouseenter?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

```
ToolStripMenuItem s;
        private void recentFilesToolStripMenuItem_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lines != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    s = new ToolStripMenuItem(lines[i]);
                    if (!recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
                        .Cast<ToolStripMenuItem>()
                        .Any(x => x.Text == lines[i]))
                    {
                        recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(s);
                        s.Click += s_Click;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It's never pass the IF checking.

I need that it will check if the items(lines) exist in the recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems so it will not add them more then once each time i'm enetering with the mouse. And also will register to the s.Click once i'm clicking on item.

EDIT this is my form1 constructor where i read the text file RecentFiles.txt and add the lines as items to the DropDownItems:

```
RecentFiles = @"e:\RecentFiles.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(RecentFiles))
            {
                recentfiles = new StreamWriter(RecentFiles);
                recentfiles.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(RecentFiles);
                items = File
                        .ReadLines(RecentFiles)
                        .Select(line => new ToolStripMenuItem()
                        {
                          Text = line
                        })
                        .ToArray();

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(RecentFiles))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (File.Exists(lines[i]))
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine(lines[i]);
                            {
                                Text = lines[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(RecentFiles);
                items = File
                        .ReadLines(RecentFiles)
                        .Select(line => new ToolStripMenuItem()
                        {
                            Text = line
                        })
                        .ToArray();
                recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);

            }
```

The content of RecentFiles.txt is:

```
d:\test.txt
d:\test1.txt
```

Comment: Which `If` are you talking about? First or Second? Is it not adding anything to `recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems `?

Comment: The second IF but i cancelled the second IF not need it. The problem is with the s.Click when i enter with the mouse i see the items(i have them added already) and when i click on one of the items it does nothing. I wanted to make that when i enter with the mouse and click on one of items it will do something. But when i enter with the mouse it already register to the s.Click....And when i click on item it does nothing its never getting to the s.Click event.

Comment: I don't see a `RichTextBox` (is it `x` ?); when you talk about clicking _items_, do you mean items in a `RichTextBox`? The event handler you show is an event handler for a `ToolStripMenuItem`, you'd have to handle the `Click` event of the `RichTextBox` separately.

Comment: Can you please add what is there in `lines` and in `recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems` ? Does it already have the things in `lines` ?

Comment: The solution is in the mouseenter event: recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems[1].Click += s_Click; this is working. Just the loop instead over lines i loop over recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count and then instead [1] just [i] working great.